# MIPS: Is it possible to print the value that is inside storage that contains .word?

Tags: mips

i am currently learning MIPS and i have a question about MIPS. As the question title, is it possible to print a value that is inside a storage that declared with ".word"

**EX:**

```
.data   

      var1: .word 3
.text

.globl main

      main:

       li $v0, 4
       la $a0, var1
       syscall
```

So is it possible for it to printed about the value 3 from var1?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just load the word from that address:

```
la $a0, var1
lw $a0, ($a0)
```

Or, if you wanted to, you could replace those two instructions with a single `lw`:

```
lw $a0, var1
```

Note that this is a pseudo-instruction, which the assembler will translate into 1 or more actual instructions. So you're not gaining anything at the machine code level, but your assembly code will be more compact.